# how to write this romove_stopwords faster python?

Tags: python, pandas, stop-words

I have a function `remove_stopwords` like this. How do I make it run faster?

```
temp.reverse()

def drop_stopwords(text):
    
    for x in temp:
        elif len(x.split()) > 1:
            text_list = text.split()  
            for y in range(len(text_list)-len(x.split())):
                if " ".join(text_list[y:y+len(x.split())]) == x:
                    del text_list[y:y+len(x.split())]
                    text = " ".join(text_list)
        
        else:
            text = " ".join(text for text in text.split() if text not in vietnamese)

    return text
```

time to solve a text in my data is 14s and if I have some trick like this time for will decrease to 3s:

```
temp.reverse()

def drop_stopwords(text):
    
    for x in temp:
        if len(x.split()) >2:
            if x in text:
                text = text.replace(x,'')

        elif len(x.split()) > 1:
            text_list = text.split()  
            for y in range(len(text_list)-len(x.split())):
                if " ".join(text_list[y:y+len(x.split())]) == x:
                    del text_list[y:y+len(x.split())]
                    text = " ".join(text_list)
        
        else:
            text = " ".join(text for text in text.split() if text not in vietnamese)

    return text
```

but I think it may get wrong some where in my language. How can I rewrite this function in Python to make it faster (in C and C++ I can solve it easily with the function above :(( )

Comment: Your first function isn't syntactically valid (you have an `if` with no `elif`), and you don't say what `temp` is or what the `text` input might look like, so it's impossible to try to run your second function either.

Comment: Please fix your first code and remove additional parts that are not needed.

Comment: i had add tag stopword to this question, so my question about how to remove stopwords from a text. temp is list of my stopwords. And i found the answer below so i think i'll keep my code for everyone who have the same hobit like me will know how to clean this code. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does a lot of the same thing over and over, particularly repeated `split` and `join` of the same `text`.  Doing a single `split`, operating on the list, and then doing a single `join` at the end might be faster, and would definitely lead to simpler code.  Unfortunately I don't have any of your sample data to test the performance with, but hopefully this gives you something to experiment with:

```
temp = ["foo", "baz ola"]


def drop_stopwords(text):
    text_list = text.split()
    text_len = len(text_list)
    for word in temp:
        word_list = word.split()
        word_len = len(word_list)
        for i in range(text_len + 1 - word_len):
            if text_list[i:i+word_len] == word_list:
                text_list[i:i+word_len] = [None] * word_len
    return ' '.join(t for t in text_list if t)


print(drop_stopwords("the quick brown foo jumped over the baz ola dog"))
# the quick brown jumped over the dog
```

You could also just try iteratively doing `text.replace` in all cases and seeing how that performs compared to your more complex `split`-based solution:

```
temp = ["foo", "baz ola"]


def drop_stopwords(text):
    for word in temp:
        text = text.replace(word, '')
    return ' '.join(text.split())


print(drop_stopwords("the quick brown foo jumped over the baz ola dog"))
# the quick brown jumped over the dog
```

Comment: sorry, my code not good. i can't use the 2nd answer because in my language, it may got false. thanks for clean my code. I though it was better if i separate it into many case will help it run faster :((